# How to create an analyzed Elastic Search ingested data in both String and Numeric format for searching?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have incoming data with a field called "PhoneNumber". It is a String and can have numeric and  special chars - ex: 123-456-7890, +123-456-7890.
I have the current requirement for searching:

1. RangeQuery - ex: 123456-99999999 will return all phonenumbers inclusive for that range
2. RegexQuery - ex: 123***4444 will return via regex 123[0-9][0-9][0-9]4444 all the phone numbers
   I initially tried the mapping:

   "PhoneNumber" :{
   "type":"text",
   "fields": {
   "textNum": {
   "type": "text",
   "analyzer": "phone_analyzer" }}}

   “phone_analyzer":{
   "char_filter":["digits"],
   "type":"custom",
   "tokenizer":"standard"}

   "char_filter":{
   "digits": {
   "type": "pattern_replace",
   "pattern": "[^0-9]",
   "replacement":""}}

Which will give me the TEXT version of only digits which can satisfy query via regex. However, I discovered that I can't do the analyzer/normalizer on numerics/longs. What can I do to have the numerical versions of the value of the text? Some examples would be hugely appreciated.
Range query only works on numerical so thats why I have to have a number format to search.
Thanks!